# Angular: valueChanges on child component in Parent component to use switchmap

Tags: angular

I have child `SearchComponent` emitting search text to parent `ErrorsListComponent` component.
Parent component sends it to `ErrorsGettingService` service, this service emit results and passes them back to `ErrorsListComponent`.

But if i quickly type multiple letters in input inside `SearchComponent` i get jumping results in `ErrorsListComponent`. I need something like `valueChanges` and `switchMap` on input inside `SearchComponent` in parent component, but i don't know how to acheive this.

```
export class ErrorsListComponent  {
  p:number;
  itemsPerPage:number= 50;
  errorLogs$:Observable<IErrorLog[]>; 

  constructor (private service :ErrorsGettingService)
  {    
    this.errorLogs$=this.service.getResults();    
  }

  public  doSearch(searchVal:string):void
  {
    this.service.setSearch(searchVal);
  }
}

export class ErrorsGettingService {

  initResponse:IErrorLog[] = null;
  subject = new BehaviorSubject<IErrorLog[] >(this.initResponse);

  _baseUrl:string;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
    @Inject(TERMINAL_URL) terminalUrl: string) { 
      this._baseUrl = terminalUrl;          
      this.setSearch(null);
     }    

public setSearch(newSearchText:string):void{  
  this.subject.next(null);
  let url=`${this._baseUrl}api/errors`;

  if (newSearchText!=null && newSearchText.length>0) 
   url=`${this._baseUrl}api/errors?filter=${newSearchText}`;

 this.http.get<IErrorLog[]>(url).pipe(   
   debounceTime(300)).toPromise().then(res=>{  
   this.subject.next(res);
  })
 /* .subscribe(
    res=> { this.subject.next(res); subscription.unsubscribe();}); */ 
}

public getResults():Observable<IErrorLog[]>
{
 return  this.subject.asObservable();
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a Subject in `ErrorsGettingService` and add values to it whenever you are getting new values.

```
let parentSubject: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>()
```

under `setSearch()`

```
parentSubject.next(searchString);

parentSubject.pipe((switchMap(() => {
    return this.http.get<IErrorLog[]>(url).pipe(   
        // debounceTime(300)).toPromise().then(res=>{  
        // this.subject.next(res);
    })
}))).subscribe(() => {
    // rest of your code
})
```

Whenever new values will be added to `parentSubject`, your previous "HTTP" requests will be cancelled, you can also chai  this with `debounceTime()`

Comment: seems that only parentSubject.next(searchString) shuold be in setSearch, and pipe in another method , and subsribe is redundant if i use async pipe in component, yes?

Comment: Don't understand full code in service, provide code please

Comment: @LapenkovVladimir yes, if you are using `async` pipe in template then subscribe shouldn't be done.

Comment: @LapenkovVladimir I have a example which works on `input`, check the console logs, the requests are simulated for a delay of 2 seconds, if you keep typing then the previously made requests will be cancelled. See if you understand this. you can use the same logic in your case. https://stackblitz.com/edit/switchmapwitinputandsubject?file=src/app/app.component.ts